# Uploading wav file from browser to AWS S3 returning empty file

Tags: ajax, amazon-s3, wav

I am recording audio data (saved as a .wav file) from my browser and attempting to upload it to an AWS S3 bucket with ajax.

The code is working in that it is making it to the AWS S3 bucket, but once in the bucket, the files appear to be empty and when downloaded, are not playing anything.

I am using `formData` to append the data of the blob file, and when i `console.log` out my blob file, I can see it's an `audio/wav` file type and how big the contents of the file is. So to me, it seems like that part is working, and i can play the file in the browser.

Here is my ajax request which is triggered from an `onClick` event

```
 upload.addEventListener("click", function(event){

  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', blob, filename);

  $.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    crossDomain: true,
    url: uploadPreSignedUrl,
    contentType: 'binary/octet-stream',
    processData: false,
    data: formData
  }).success(function(success) {
    console.log('success', success);
  }).error(function(error) {
    console.log('error', error)
  })
})
```

Does anyone see potentially why the form data I'd be attaching to the ajax request would be showing up as empty on AWS S3? I can attach more code if needed

Any help is very appreciated!